# Reading Table in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read the data from this table:

[image: TABLE].

I want to make a vector for each category with its corresponding width. So I'm trying to get a vector for highway showing `[315.31 105.37 213.13]` and a vector for commerical showing `[420.13 343.36]`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I read in the file as a .csv file (seen below).

```
roads <- read.csv("D:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\R\\roads.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Just use `split` i.e `split(roads$width, roads$category)`

Comment: I think there are dupes for this post (though I couldn't find one)

Comment: I tried looking for duplicates also but couldn't find any. And thank you for your answer. So I did `mylist <- split(roads$width, roads$category)`. How would I get just the "commercial" values out of this?

Comment: you can get by `mylist[[1]]` , `mylist[[2]]`

Comment: Thank you again for answering. I kept getting issues trying `mylist[[1]]` so I tried unlisting and everything is working.

Comment: If you `unlist`, it will be a single vector